# CSS error on my webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm making a new theme but I have a little problem... [Click here to see my design](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar/). As you can see, the dark container background is only behind the 'DaniThemes' logo but I want it to occupy the whole structure. Here you have the codes I'm using:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}


#content {
width:1000px;
height:auto;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
color: #fff;
padding:20px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your floats. Add a [clearfix](https://www.google.com/search?q=clearfix) to your `div#content`.

css:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; 
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="content" class="cf">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with the id='content'.
An id is meant to be unique, so using it on multiple elements will cause problems.

Start with that and then check back with whats up.